# Limits of generative models

Tags: generative-models

If I was to train a pixel rnn, by concatenating images with noise vectors, I should be able to get new images from that distribution by starting on the prediction with a new noise vector. Would it be possible to use medication packet leaflets instead of images or as the images, and generate new drugs complete with description this way? If so, how big a dataset would be required and if not, what are the limitations to this approach?

Comment: I have heard of no company that is currently creating new drugs by training generative models on medication packet leaflets. Would even smartest humans be able to do this if you just provide this information and nothing else? You can find out about state of art of various ML models from scientific papers, for example by reading preprints on arxiv.org.